# Can not generate designer.cs / Can not change Access Modifier of .resx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, resources

I've got a (ASP.Net)Web Site with some resource files. Normally a designer.cs file should be generated under the resource.resx file. But in my case it didn't. I read online you can generate one with either setting your access modifier to public or use a custom tool. Both these things seem to not work for me:

No Access Modifier available:

[image: No Access Modifier]

No Custom Tool Properties:

[image: No CustomTool properties]

What should I do to make this work?

Comment: A `resx` file does not have a `designer.cs` file.

Comment: It does in a Windows.Forms application.

Comment: Then why did you label your question with `asp.net` if the qestion is about winforms?

Comment: Because for my asp.net application they don't so I can't link them to my Dependency Injection